# Adding a custom preset build configuration to make

Tags: make, busybox

I'm building busybox from source and I have more than one configuration. (For different uses) As I have it now, each time I want to build something, I have to copy the correct .config file to the source folder, type 'make' wait, copy the next .config file and so forth. I would like to implement the .config files so, that I can simply type 'make custom1config; make' and 'make custom2config; make' etc...

I tried copying the .configs to SOURCE/configs, where there were other preset files, but sadly that doesn't work. make complains that it doesn't have proper rules to use them.

So the question is, how could I add proper custom configs for 'make' to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in an argument when executing your make script that contains the path to the configuration file. Then run make as usual.

```
CONFIG_FILE="default.cfg"

all:
    @echo "Default Make: ${CONFIG_FILE}"

run:
    @echo "Running: ${CONFIG_FILE}"
```

You can call `make` and you'll get the default value or you can call `make CONFIG_FILE="./configs/custom1.cfg"` and you'll replace the variable in the Makefile. You can also have non-default targets that work the same way.

```
jeff@rpi2-home:[~/custommake]$ make
Default Make: default.cfg
jeff@rpi2-home:[~/custommake]$ make CONFIG_FILE="./configs/custom1.cfg"
Default Make: ./configs/custom1.cfg
jeff@rpi2-home:[~/custommake]$ make run
Running: Default Parameter
jeff@rpi2-home:[~/custommake]$ make CONFIG_FILE="./configs/custom1.cfg" run
Running: ./configs/custom1.cfg
```

Comment: Thanks, based on the idea, I made a script that builds the binaries for me. I can tell it to use specific compilers and config files :)